# How to create a sum column without an internal subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a complex query which I need to have a conditionally summed column for it.

Here is a simplified version of my query and results:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, condition int, value int); 

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES (1,1,12), (2,0,88), (3,1,11)

SELECT 
     *, 
    (SELECT SUM(value) FROM @t WHERE condition = 1) as SumOfConditionalValues 
FROM @t
```

Here are the results of this query"

```
id  condition   value   SumOfConditionalValues
1   1           12      23
2   0           88      23
3   1           11      23
```

I can't afford the `SumOfConditionalValues` sub query.

Is there an elegant way to achieve the conditionally summed column without it?

Which aggregate commands are suitable here, if any, and how do I apply these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN condition = 1 THEN value END) OVER() SumOfConditionalValues
FROM @t
```

Comment: @bluefeet - This answer passed all my tests, even on real data and the complex query. What problems should I look for?

Comment: @elarrow there are no problems with this answer. This answer solved the problem without using a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @elarrow - There shouldn't be any problems per se. Maybe you should test the performance of this query against the one given by AnandPhadke to see if there is some difference on your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1abea/1

Use a self join:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id int, condition int, value int); 

INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES (1,1,12), (2,0,88), (3,1,11)

SELECT
  MyTable.id,
  MyTable.Condition,
  MyTable.value,
  SUM(JoinedMyTable.Value)
FROM
  MyTable
  LEFT JOIN MyTable JoinedMyTable ON MyTable.condition = JoinedMyTable.Condition
GROUP BY
  MyTable.id,
  MyTable.Condition,
  MyTable.value
```

EDIT: Don't know if you want every row to show the sum of rows where condition = 1, but if you do just change the join clause to be:

```
LEFT JOIN MyTable JoinedMyTable ON JoinedMyTable.Condition = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the "CASE' statement...Very powerful, for example:

```
  select id, sum(case when condition=1 then value else 0 end) group by id..etc
```

Comment: This won't give what he wants, since op wants the same value of the sum for every record on the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @sum int
SELECT @sum=SUM(value) FROM @t WHERE condition = 1
select *,@sum from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the results aggregated by condition:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, condition int, value int); 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1,1,12), (2,0,88), (3,1,11)
SELECT *, 
sum(value) over (partition by condition) as SumOfConditionalValues 
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT id, condition, value,   
      SUM(CASE WHEN condition = 1 THEN value_at_1 END) OVER() SumOfConditionalValues
FROM (select *,
             (case when condition = 1 then value end) as value_at_1
      from @t
     ) t
```

You need a "conditional value", which you can create in a subquery.